# Masonry & Load More

Tags: jquery, masonry

I'm having a hard time understanding how to apply Masonry to a page when LOAD MORE in place. I've found similar examples, and tried applying the code to my case, but it's not working.

Here's where I've put up a dummy site http://test.pamplemoussejournal.com/

This is what I have for my masonry settings

```js
var $container = jQuery('#masonry-grid');


$container.imagesLoaded( function(){
   jQuery('#masonry-grid').show();
   jQuery('#loading').hide();
    
   $container.masonry({ 
     itemSelector: '.item', 
     columnWidth: 325,
     isFitWidth: true,
    isAnimated: true
   }); 

})
```

When I look into the inspector, the divs are loading but not loading masonry

```
<div id="masonry-grid" style="position: relative; width: 1300px; height: 916px;">

<div class="item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;"></div>
<div class="item" style="position: absolute; left: 325px; top: 0px;"></div>
<div class="item" style="position: absolute; left: 650px; top: 0px;"></div>
<div class="item" style="position: absolute; left: 975px; top: 0px;"></div>
<div class="item" style="position: absolute; left: 325px; top: 316px;"></div>
<div class="item" style="position: absolute; left: 650px; top: 406px;"></div>
<div class="item" style="position: absolute; left: 975px; top: 423px;"></div>
<div class="item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 442px;"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
```

I don't feel like append is what I need to be using, I think masonry('reload') is what I need, but I can't quite figure it out, because everything I've tried has had zero effect.

Thanks for any help or pointers.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar issue and I resolve with the following code:

```
//Here I attach the new loaded items (html var) in the #container div.
$("#masonry-grid").append(html).each(function(){
   $('#masonry-grid').masonry('reloadItems');
});         

$('#masonry-grid').imagesLoaded(function(){
   $('#masonry-grid').masonry();
});
```

If you want to see it working and the effect, you could visit http://pintevent.com to see if is the same desired behavior. Hope it helps!